# S3 to SFTP sync operator

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, airflow, sftp

I appreciate the **S3ToSFTPOperator**:

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-amazon/stable/_api/airflow/providers/amazon/aws/transfers/s3_to_sftp/index.html

for moving specific files from S3 to SFTP.

But with Boto3 / aws cli it is also possible to use the `sync` operation to synchronise from a source location into a target location all the files in the source one:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html

I wonder if there is a way to have the target location for this `sync` to an SFTP location in Airflow?

Comment: `sync` it is only feature of CLI interface, and Amazon do not provide it in SDK/API. in another word there is no such functionality into the `botocore` or [`boto3`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html)

Comment: Alternatively, you could: [Send and retrieve files by using an SFTP connector - AWS Transfer Family](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/transfer/latest/userguide/transfer-sftp-connectors.html) It effectively syncs S3 to an external SFTP server.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein thanks for the input, I see `transfer` is available in the CLI, is it also available in Boto3? Does it also have the `sync` feature as is available in the S3 CLI tool? I guess I could implement it myself but I'd rather use something robust that is already existing if available

Comment: No, the `sync` capability in the AWS CLI is for Amazon S3 operations only. The SFTP connector has different commands as listed on the page linked above.